# How do I make the frontend non-interactive in Arch Linux?

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, zsh, environment-variables, manjaro

In Debian, we have a variable called `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`, which when set to `noninteractive` stops prompting and is useful in scripts. Do we have an equivalent in archlinux? Because, 'echo y | ' is really annoying when the script has 20 different lines

Comment: what frontend are you referring to?

Comment: @Fox Umm the shell frontend

Comment: ... instead of `echo y`, consider `yes`

Comment: `How do I make the frontend` What "frontend"? "Frontend" to what end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have an equivalent in archlinux?

No, you need to pass `--noconfirm` option to `pacman`.

> is really annoying when the script has 20 different lines

In scripts I like to "mask" the command with function:

```
pacman() {
   command pacman --noconfirm "$@"
}
pacman -S something
# really runs pacman --noconfirm -S something
```